# Navbar in Bootstrap not working properly in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement simple bootstrap Navbar in my asp.net page. 
I found lots of examples but it's working perfectly only in html pages but not working properly on my asp.net page.

i can't able to post my pictures here.. always giving errors

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Static Navbar Extended</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bs-example {
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="bs-example">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my asp.net page output looks

https://ibb.co/eY85n6

and my html page code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Static Navbar Extended</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bs-example {
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my html page output shows perfectly
https://ibb.co/hFizEm

the out put is totally different..(in asp.net Login link push down) what i am doing wrong

Comment: What is the error in the console, if any?

Comment: please check both outputs                                                                   
asp.net: https://ibb.co/eY85n6                                                                   html output: https://ibb.co/hFizEm

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have 2 forms, one just inside the body and another one for search. Change the second form to div.

```
<!--change this form to div-->
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

this might lead to different issues later but it should take care of the styling problem.